# Using document.open or javascript to open a file from a url in a popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code which works fine but is there a way to open a file this way?

```
var a = window.open('', '', 'width=662,height=580,resizable=1,scrollbars=1,left=' + x + ',top=' + y + ',screenX=' + x + ',screenY=' + y);

a.document.open("text/html");
a.document.write("<html><body><div>");
a.document.write(output);
a.document.write("</div></body></html>");
a.document.close();
a.print();
//a.close();
```

I want a url to be open instead of all the document.writes.

Comment: Like this? `window.open("http://www.w3schools.com");`

Comment: let's back up and instead of asking how to open a file, explain what you then want to do with that file. What are you trying to do that requires opening a file in a tab?

Comment: I want a popup of a file in a new window with print options.